# How to remove auto create space while choose suggestion on keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
AppTextField(
                         maxLength: 40,
                         controller: emailC,
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                             horizontal: 10, vertical: 2),
                         hintText: 'youremail@gmail.com',
                         onChanged: () {},
                         width: Get.width,
                         textColor: AppColors.primary,
                         elevation: 0,
                         textFieldColor: AppColors.textField,
                         height: 47,
                         textStyle: AppTextStyle.regularBlack14,
                       ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I have previously ended up using a `validator` to process the user input, and removing the extra space there. If spaces are not allowed, you could also `.strip()` the value in the value changed callback.

Take a look at the simple validator example from the docs: [text form field with validation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation#2-add-a-textformfield-with-validation-logic).

And there, you could have something like this:

```dart
valideInput(value) {
  // strip trailing spaces
  value = value.strip();

  // actual validation like empty checks
  if (value == null || value.length == 0) return 'Please enter a value!';

  return null;
}
```

Comment: validation has appropriately worked but when I select keyboard suggestion email/data then create space that's the issue I want to remove

Comment: I understand, but what I mean is that if you strip the value in the validator, it'll remove the trailing space when the value is submitted. Or even, if you validate on every change, whenever a space is added.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Completetly successful 

setState(() {
      formatedEmail = emailC.text.replaceAll(' ', '');
});
```